# "No such file or dir" when using bash to automate wallpaper selection - NixOS

Tags: bash, nixos

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

Wallpaper_Dir="~/.config/hypr/Wallpapers/" #using full path in my code

chosen=$(ls $Wallpaper_Dir --ignore='Best Wallpapers.md' | rofi -dmenu -i)

swww img "$Wallpaper_Dir'$chosen'" # I added the extra quotes so that if the image name contains a space it is still able to work
```

this code returns this error:

`Error: "failed to open image: No such file or directory (os error 2)"`

in terms of bug testing I have tried to echo: `swww img "$Wallpaper_Dir'$chosen'"`
and it returns `swww img ~/.config/hypr/Wallpapers/'Chill Study.jpg'` which looks fine, note that I use the full path not `~` in my code, wondering if anyone could shed some light as to why

Comment: I'm hardly an expert, but have you made sure that the path `"$Wallpaper_Dir'$chosen'"` actually does exist and point to an image? Cause I can imagine that `"~/.config/hypr/Wallpapers/'Wallpaper.png'"` might be kinda hard to find. Try getting rid of the single quotes around `$chosen` and see if that helps.

Comment: yeah I tried running the command by its self and it works

Comment: Exactly as posted in your question? With the single quotes inside the string?

Comment: yeah exactly like this: swww img ~/.config/hypr/Wallpapers/'Chill Study.jpg'

bear in mind I am using ~ instead of my actual home path, but when I did it I used the actual path

Comment: Huh...afraid I can't help you then I don't have that system to test the usecase either.

Comment: Alright well thanks for trying!

Comment: Drop single quotes. Double quotes already handle spaces.

Comment: `~` has to be unquoted to have special meeting.

Answer (score 0):

```
~/.config/hypr/Wallpapers/'Chill Study.jpg'
```

from [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78224990/no-such-file-or-dir-when-using-bash-to-automate-wallpaper-selection-nixos/78227319#comment137908391_78224990) is not the same thing as:

```
"~/.config/hypr/Wallpapers/'Chill Study.jpg'"
```

from your code (expanded from `Wallpaper_Dir="~/.config/hypr/Wallpapers/" ... "$Wallpaper_Dir'$chosen'"` and assuming `$chosen` has the value `Chill Study.jpg`)

In the first case, `.../'Chill Study.jpg'`, the `'`s are quotes read by the shell so that the spaces are treated as literal characters in your file name, but in the second case, `".../'Chill Study.jpg'"`, the `'` themselves are inside a double quoted string and so the `'`s as well as the spaces are treated as literal characters in your file name.

Please read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes to learn about quotes and there are other issues with your script too, some of which http://shellcheck.net could help you with.